# Need to re-link a data source to a letter in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I have several document letters that are linked to a data base, most are working correctly.  I am having trouble with one that I believe the link was severed.  I can get it to work by clicking - mailings;use existing list and clicking the proper list.  The problem is that the link will not remain even after saving the document.  The next time I open the document I have to go through the whole process again.  These documents were originally set up in Word 97-2003 but that should not be the issue.  Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Word can, unforturtunately, retain an old data source even after you think you have changed it.

If you see the SQL prompt when you open the mail merge main document, select the No option. Then attach the correct data source and save the document.

If you don't see an SQL prompt, get through any dialogs to the point where the mail merge main document is open. Then in the Mailings tab, Start Mail Merge, select Normaol Word Document. That should remove the existing data source. Save/close/re-open, just to be sure, then attach the data source that you want, and save again.

Comment: The second part of your answer is where I am having my problem.  I don't see an SQL prompt and in the mail merge main document I click the mailings tab, start mail merge (actually select recipents), save/close/reopen and then how do I attach the data source that I want?

Comment: Go back into the Mailings tab, then use Select Recipients->Use existing list. After that, it depends on the type of data source. What is the data source? But start there and see how that goes.